# Navbar above the content (like in an above layer)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put my navbar under my big header, but it is going in the front of it, isn't just even above it but kinda in the front

[image: showing the problem]

In the code the navbar it's under the "Debugando" but it is showing above it, i want it to stay under it but it is not working i can't find why. I think is something about the position or the float.

Code( First Css then html ):

```css
body {
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 font-family: Josefin Sans, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
 background: #428F48;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 0px;

 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.nav {
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav-pills>li {
 font-size: 24px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.jumbotron {
 background: #27b032;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 position: absolute;
}

.title {
 font-size: 80px;
 margin-left: 10%;
 padding:  40px 0 40px 0;

 float: left; 
}

.description { 
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: 5%;
 padding-left: 3%;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 65px;

    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.description span{
 margin-top: 15px;
 position: absolute;
}

.dot {
  -webkit-animation-name: blink;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;


  animation-name: blink;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  
  25% {opacity: 100;}
  50% {opacity: 0;}
  25% {opacity: 100;}

}

@keyframes blink {
  25% {opacity: 100;}
  50% {opacity: 0;}
  25% {opacity: 100;}
}

html:
```

```html
<html>

<head>

 <title>Debugando</title>
 
 <meta charset="UTF-8">

 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,700&subset=latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 

</head>

<body>
 
 <!--- Top -->
 <div class="content-fluid">

  <div class="jumbotron">

      <div class="title">
       
       <span>Debugando</span><span class="dot">.</span>

      </div>
     

      <div class="description">
       
       <span>

       Descrição foda será inserida aqui.

       </span>

      </div>
     
  </div>

  <div class="navbar">
   
   <ul class="nav-pills">

    <li>Início</li>
    <li>Contato</li>

   </ul>

  </div>

 </div>

<!--<script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I can use bootstrap if needed. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I'm using the last one, but i could fix it already. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First if you are using bootstrap you'll need to add .clearfix to the div with class .jumbotron.

```
<div class="jumbotron clearfix">
```

Then remove the absolute positioning from .jumbotron

```
.jumbotron {
    background: #27b032;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Here are some resources about position absolute and float styles: [Position Absolute](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp), [Float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Comment: I could fix it before i see your answer but thank you! I did something near that, just changing what i needed because i changed my idea of the navbar :P